# FB.ui method send

Tags: facebook, api, cordova

FB app request is working on phonegap using facebook connect phonegap plugin, but the "send" method is not. 
Example:

```
FB.ui({
      method: 'send',
      link: 'http://www.eTobb.com',
      to: ''
   }, function(response) {
        console.log(response);
});
```

The `console.log(response)` is not giving me any data.

Comment: If you're not getting anything in `response`, that means this method is n't called. Pl checl

Comment: I am calling it manually.

Comment: Can you see a dialog or not?

Comment: Nothing happens, no dialogs. That's the problem. No support for send method in this plugin?

Comment: I hope you are giving a correct `to` parameter. Alos, try removing the `to` parameter and then try.

Comment: Yes i am it is just an example here.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is the ConnectPlugin.java file, which comes with the phonegap plugin (url: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin/blob/master/src/android/ConnectPlugin.java )

Check the onComplete method at line 240 and compare it to your local version of that Java file. When adding the plugin via "phonegap plugin add [long facebook github url]", it seems it does not use the latest master, but one of the releases (or likewise). But that onComplete method does not hand over the data to the Javascript in that outdated version.

So what I just did, was to get that latest master into my project and it's working now, even though it's probably not the best thing to do. :)